# Jaxb unmarshalling of abstract list in abstract class

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I am using jaxb plugin (rg.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2) to generate my java classes. So ,I am using xsd which automatically generates java classes. I want my solution to be abstract.

I have a XML

```
  <RESULTS>
    <RESULT>
      <TOKEN>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</TOKEN>
      <LANGUAGE>en</LANGUAGE>
      <SEARCHTYPE>PO</SEARCHTYPE>
    </RESULT>
  </RESULTS>
```

Later , I am going to have same XML for other product but with an extra NUMBER element

```
 <RESULTS>
    <RESULT>
      <TOKEN>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</TOKEN>
      <LANGUAGE>en</LANGUAGE>
      <SEARCHTYPE>PO</SEARCHTYPE>
      <NUMBER>123456789</NUMBER>
    </RESULT>
  </RESULTS>
```

I want to make my solution as abstract. Below is my jaxb implementation.

**1)** My Results class contains list of result. I have made this result as BaseResult.

```
   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "RESULTS", propOrder = {
        "baseresult"
    })
    public class Results implements Equals2, HashCode2, ToString2
    {

        @XmlElement(name = "BASERESULT", required = true)
        protected List<BaseResult> baseresult;
    }
```

**2)** This is my BaseResult class which has common fields.

public abstract class BaseResult implements Equals2, HashCode2, ToString2
    {

```
    @XmlElement(name = "TOKEN", required = true)
    protected String token;
    @XmlElement(name = "LANGUAGE", required = true)
    protected String language;
}
```

This is my xsd file to generate above code

```
   <xs:complexType name="RESULTS">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                    Holds results tag <!-- <RESULTS></RESULTS> -->
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="BASERESULT" type="BASERESULT" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="BASERESULT" abstract="true">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
                Holds result <!-- <RESULT></RESULT> -->token , with all common elements in result tag
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="TOKEN" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element ref="LANGUAGE" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

**3)** This is child class for result,which has child fields.

```
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "RESULT", propOrder = {
        "searchType"
    })
    public class Result extends BaseResult
        implements Equals2, HashCode2, ToString2
    {

        @XmlElement(name = "SEARCHTYPE", required = true)
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
        @XmlSchemaType(name = "NCName")
        protected String searchType;
    }
```

This is my xsd file to generate above code

```
<xs:complexType name="RESULT">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="BASERESULT">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="SEARCHTYPE" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

The issue is I am not able to make my xml as stated above.
It doesn't able to fill result in mu xml.

PLease advice

Answer (score 0):

Your problem come from this :

```
@XmlElement(name = "BASERESULT", required = true)
protected List<BaseResult> baseresult;
```

This tells that you're expecting to find a BASERESULT element in your XML.

Switch to :

```
@XmlElement(name="result")
protected List<BaseResult> baseresult;
```

With this, you'll only get your commons properties (or an error because BaseResult is abstract).

Your other problem is that you have map to which class JAXB should bind the element it finds.

What you should use is something like that :

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name="result",type=Result.class),
    @XmlElement(name="result2",type=Result2.class)
})
protected List<BaseResult> baseresult;
```

The problem is that you use the same element name for both your class.
Normally, an XML element should only be described by one class, for JAXB to find the appropriate class for binding.

So you should use differents element names in your XML for each class that extends BaseResult.

If you can't do that, i don't see any workaround that will able you to implements an abstract solution as you wish to.